# В чем разница bundle и jsonobject?

Tags: android

В чем разница этих 2-х значений, если и то и другое передает данные по схеме ключ-значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Bundle` это типобезопасный контейнер направленный на производительность чтения и записи данных и его цель - хранить и предоставлять некую информацию по типу ключ-значение, где ключ это строка, а значения - данные реализующие интерфейс `Parcelable` или наследующие класс `Parcel`, которые в свою очередь **предоставляют возможность для упаковки/распаковки данных при межпотоковом взаимодействии**(обмена данными между множеством потоков). Важно отметить что именно реализация `Parcelable` для значений `Bundle` обеспечивает возможность запаковать/распаковать объект, грубо говоря, это значит что не нужна строгая привязка к блоку памяти который использует экземпляр, так как этот экземпляр можно будет "воссоздать". Именно для этого значения должны реализовывать `Parcelable` интерфейс. Типобезопасность `Bundle` обеспечивается его способом установки/получения значений, осуществляющий доступ к типам только строго определенными, допустимыми способами. Это значит что 'положив' в Bundle значение методом `putShort()`, получить это значение можно только при помощи `getShort()` метода. В итоге получается что `Bundle` это своеобразный HashMap "заточенный" для работы с IPC (Inter-Process Communication).

В свою очередь `JsonObject`это изменяемый набор пар name/value, как и `Bundle`. Имена должны быть уникальными, не нулевыми строками, в отличии от Bundle который может принимать нулевые значения, а "неуникальное" имя(ключ) просто перезапишет существующую пару ключ-значение. Значения могут быть миксом из `JSONObject`, `JSONArray`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Double` или `JsonObject.NULL`. Значения не могут быть null, NaNs, итд. и могут принимать значения **только** выше перечесленных типов. Экземпляры этого класса **не являются потоко-безопасными**. По-сути, это класс реализованый для использования JSON протокола.

Внимательно прочитав описаные выше особенности становится очевидно то, что `Bundle` и `JsonObject` хоть и похожи на поверхности, но не имеют ничего общего в плане предназначения.

Comment: Ответ хороший, только вот вы же понимаете что такой вопрос как этот вряд ли бы задал профессионал? А ответ у вас получился как из книги по научной литературе)) я половину не понял)) можете уточнить, чтоб точно понятно было. 1)Что такое 'типобезопасный контейнер',  2)'межпотоковое взаимодействие'? 3)Вы пишите что "JsonObjectэто изменяемый набор пар" ,  значит Bundle это не изменяемый набор? 4)Имена должны быть уникальными, не нулевыми строками для JsonObject я так понял, что для Bundle это не обязательно?

Comment: @Aleks Дополнил ответ, постарался ответить на ваши вопросы.